# PG::UndefinedFile at / ERROR: could not open file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting the following error on a particular `id`, when I try to do `TestModel.find_each` everytime. Even though I am able to access that object by `find`. and on deleting that particular object, this same error with the same oid(16385) and index(19388) is occurring for the just next id. Why is this happening?

> PG::UndefinedFile at / ERROR:  could not open file
>   "base/16385/19338.2" (target block 268441506): No such file or
>   directory

Comment: Can you share the relevant code in the question. What do you do in the block passed to `find_each` method.

Comment: `TestModel.find_each do |tm|
    puts tm.id 
    end`
and this throws the above error at a particular id everytime. The error has happened many times before and I had been ignoring it (deleting that particular row and recreating makes it work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unrelated to `rails`, it's a `postgres` message indicating that a datafile is missing.

`16385` is the identifier (OID) of the database, `19338` the `relation` in PG terms (an index or a table).

You may question why a datafile disappeared from PostgreSQL data directory, this should never happen.

The advice in this case is to restore the entire database from a backup.

Maybe you'll see more errors or errors in context in the postgresql log files.

Comment: If the file is missing then why can I access it using `find`?

Comment: and now when I just deleted that particular object, this same error with the same oid and index is occurring for the just next id..

Comment: @bhuwan And that means that you have a broken database. The database may know that a row with a particular `id` exists from the primary key index but the row itself (and other rows) may be missing.

Comment: @muistooshort What does "a row with a particular id exists from the primary key index but the row itself (and other rows) may be missing" means? i.e. If the row doesn't exist then how can the data for that particular id is retrievable? Sorry I didn't get it. Also why deleting the object with that particular id is making the same error to occur for the next id. And is there any way to resolve such errors?

Comment: The PK index knows that the row is supposed to exist because that's part of what indexes do. But you have a corrupted database so the actual row data does not exist. Think of it as a dangling pointer. This answer already tells you how to resolve these errors: restore the entire database from a backup. If you don't have backups then you get to learn about backups the hard way: start fresh with an empty database and lose all your data.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. Can you suggest what all can be the possible reasons for a broken database?

Comment: Dodgy harddrive, file system corruption, improperly copying files, ... the usual suspects. In any case, it is almost certainly too late now to recover your database.